# How to merge and asort() two object arrays into one new array?

Tags: php, object

```
function sortnmerge($array1,$array2)
$all= array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
asort($all);
```

While this works for regular arrays, is there a way to apply it to two array of objects or more?

$all would be the result of merging both contact lists.

Thank you in advance,

JP-

Comment: Are `$array1` and `$array2` actually arrays, or object arrays (i.e.: ArrayAccess)?

Comment: They are object arrays in fact: ArrayAccess using your previous  implementation and solution which worked just great for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
   function arrayobj_merge_recursive2($paArray1, $paArray2)
{
    if(is_array($paArray2))
    {
        foreach ($paArray2 AS $sKey2 => $sValue2)
        {
            $paArray1[$sKey2] = arrayobj_merge_recursive2(@$paArray1[$sKey2], $sValue2);
        }
    }
    elseif(is_object($paArray2))
    {   
        foreach ($paArray2 AS $sKey2 => $sValue2)
        {
             $paArray1->{$sKey2} = arrayobj_merge_recursive2(@$paArray1->{$sKey2}, $sValue2);
        } 
    } else {
         return $paArray2;
    }  
   return $paArray1;
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps: define a function to compare the objects, then call `usort($all, "cmp")`. Example:

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a->some_value > $b->some_value;
}

function sortnmerge($arr1, $arr2) {
    $all = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
    usort($all, "cmp");
}
?>
```

I assume, of course, that you're trying to merge two arrays of objects and then compare them based on some property.